# Error after making jar file of project

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm new in javaFX. I created application in javaFX it has maven inside of project when I'm running project in idea it works perfectly. But after making it jar I can't print it it after clicking print button it gives me following errors.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.h andleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1267032364.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRException
        at sample.Controller.checkfinish(Controller.java:212)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 58 more
```

my program structure look like following:

[image: image of project structure]

and my pom.xml looks like following.I add more build and another dependecies into my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>QassaCopy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>

                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>

                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib/</outputDirectory>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>classes/lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>

                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you miss the jasperreports jar in the classpath at runtime

Comment: To support Jens' comment, you can see that jasperreports is missing by the the two lines in the stack trace: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRException` and `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException`.

Comment: this two error lines is dissapear but print still dosn't work

Comment: after Adding jasperreports jar into project

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/NestedNu
llException this give this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your pom.xml jasper dependencies:

```
<project>
**********************************
<properties>
    <jasperReport.version>yourversion</jasperReport.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>${jasperReport.version}</version>
</dependency>
**********************************
</project>
```

then go to the root folder of the project using command line and then run this comand:

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/NestedNu
llException
        at sample.PrintNew.print(PrintNew.java:24)
        at sample.Controller.checkfinish(Controller.java:214)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.Nested
NullException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Could you please show what exactly you added into you pom.xml?

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: 1. Remove superfluous build from you pom.xml. After tag <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: OK I left only this

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>QassaCopy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

     


    
</project>

Comment: could you please show whole pom file? And it would be better if you add it in `code`  format

Comment: `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>QassaCopy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging> `

Comment: then add your dependencies `<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>`

Comment: `<build><finalName>QassaCopy</finalName>
<plugins><plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.8</source>
<target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</plugin>
</plugins></build>
</project>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code as well to build it.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib/</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>classes/lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```